# Lambda expression NotContains operator Exists?

Tags: c#, lambda

Lambda expression for `Contains` operator I am able to generate using this code.

**Expression**

```
Company => Company.Name.Contains("test1")
```

**Source code**

```
var method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) }); 
var startsWithDishExpr = Expression.Call(argLeft, method, argRight);
```

Its working fine for `Contains` operator.
How to modify to code to work for `NotContains` operator.

**Source code**

```
var method = typeof(string).GetMethod("NotContains", new[] { typeof(string) }); 
var startsWithDishExpr = Expression.Call(argLeft, method, argRight);
```

`NotContains` operator not working. Anybody have suggestion?

Comment: What about combining a simple `not` operator with a call to `Contains`? i.e. `Expression.Not(Expression.Call(containsMethod,...))`

Comment: Your first sample is creating a call to the `string.Contains` method. There's no such method as `string.NotContains`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Oops, I did not see your comment right away. Post it as an answer, I'll upvote it :)

Comment: @CodesInChaos: And if you do post it as an answer, please don't forget a good explanation of why it works like this and why it didn't work the way the OP tried, as already mentioned by Jon. Then I'll upvote the answer, too.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is no `string.NotContains` method, so creating a call to a method called `NotContains` doesn't work.

A simple solution is to combine the `not` operator, with the `Contains` method. Just like normally you'd write `!x.Contains(y)` and not `x.NotContains(y)`.

To create such an expression you can use [`Expression.Not(callExpression)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299047.aspx).

Comment: CodesInChaos, Expression.Not(callExpression), great it worked for NotContains. Thanks